# Return pointer on 2d Array from a function

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers

I'm new to C and trying to change the return type of a function. The problem is that, for example, these work:

```
float fct(int)
```

```
float *fct(float)
```

But when I try to change the return type to:

```
float (*)[n]fct(int *n)
```

The compiler issues an error:

> *error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘)’ token*

Even if it tells me to change the return type to `float (*)[n]`.

It would be awesome if someone could explain what the issue is.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is:

```
float (*fct(int *n))[SIZE];
```

I should note that the compiler won't like it if `SIZE` is not a constant value.

The pointer must have an identifier which in this case is `fct(int *n)`,
it's as if you had something like `(*ptr)[SIZE]` only `ptr` is `fct(int *n)`.

The compiler message omits the pointer identifier, as usual. It just tells you what the type should be and that is `float (*)[n]`. If, for example, the return type was to be pointer to `int` it would tell you the return type should be `int*`.

Now, on a different note, `n` size doesn't make much sense because you use in the function as a parameter, as a pointer to `int`.

You must also be careful *not* to return a pointer to a locally (in the function) declared array, you will need to allocate memory for it if you want it to outlive the function.